# Can I smoothly zoom in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, zoom

Simple question here: Is it possible to zoom smoothly in Illustrator CC? Like in Photoshop CC?

I can only alt+mousewheel zoom now but that's more of a snap zoom then a smooth zoom.

Comment: Isn't it in the preference panel?

Answer (score 4):

You need to go to Preferences > GPU Performance... and check the box next to "Enable Animated Zoom". Once you have done this, clicking and dragging with the zoom tool will give you the smooth scrubby zoom effect.

Comment: Under Edit>Preferences, I don't have a 'GPU Performance' option. I would really like to enable scrubby zoom if possible. What do I need to do?

Comment: @ThomasMyron: If I remember rightly, this option was introduced in Illustrator CC. If you are using an earlier version then it is not an option.

Comment: I'm using CS5, so that's probably what's going on. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also press <kbd>z</kbd> and drag the mouse.

This works as of CC 2017